# Find if any combination with unique elements <=2 in list of sets

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I have a algorithm issue to find similar Ids in large set, but could not figure out a way with good performance. Here is the detail.

```
Find if any combination (contains target set) with unique elements <=2 in list of sets.

Definition for unique elements: same as [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)

Example 1:
Target list: [1,2,3,4]
List of sets: {[1,2,3]}
The unique elements is [4,5], which size is 1 <=2, so it is false;

Example 2:
Target list: [1,2,3,4,5]
List of sets: {[1],[2],[3]}
The unique elements is [4,5], which size is 1 <=2, so it is false;

Example 3:
Target list: [1,2,3,4]
List of sets: {[1],[2,7],[3,7],[4,8]}
The unique elements is [8], which size is 1 <=2, so it is false;

Example 4:
Target list: [1,2,3,4]
List of sets: {[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
The unique elements is [5,6,7], which size is 3 > 2, so it is true;
```

**Thought:**
The only idea from me is to list the permutation for all the combination:
start from most 2 sets, then 3 sets, and so on. For each permutation, get their unique elements, if find any unique elements <= 2, return false.

Use "Example2" as example:
1. First list permutation for max 2 sets {[1,2,3,4,5],[1]},{[1,2,3,4,5],[2]},{[1,2,3,4,5],[3]}, didn't find unique elements <=2 case;
2. Then list permutation for max 3 sets {[1,2,3,4,5],[1],[2]},{[1,2,3,4,5],[1],[3]},{[1,2,3,4,5],[2],[3]}, didn't find unique elements <=2 case;
3. Finally list permutation for max 4 sets, there is only 1 situation {[1,2,3,4,5],[1],[2],[3]}, find unique elements [4,5] size <=2 case, return false.

**Question:**
Issue is the **performance**, it is too slow, let's say size of "list of sets" is n, permutation size is r.
The complexity for permutation is **p(n, r)/r=n!/r(n-r)!**, which increase significantly when n and r grow bigger,

when n = 50 and r = 5, the permutation size is 2118760,
but when n = 100 and r = 10, the permutation size is 17310309456440.

The complexity just too bad for the large n and r, is there a better way/algorithm to solve this issue?